# Get number of ratings and categories for each product, in list of products, with one database call

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by

I have 4 tables: 1 item table, 1 category table, 1 item_to_category table, and a review table which holds review of each item.

An item can be in many categories.

I want to get a PHP array, which lists each item, the categories the item is in, and the number of review the item has.

Is this possible using a single database call?

This query

```
    $q = 'SELECT `items`.`id` as item_id, `category`.`id` as category_id, COUNT(`review_id`) AS review_count
    FROM  `items`
    JOIN  `item_to_category` ON  `item_to_category`.`item_id` =  `items`.`id`
    JOIN  `category` ON  `category`.`id` =  `item_to_category`.`id`
    JOIN  `reviews` ON `items`.`id` = `reviews`.`item_id`
    WHERE `items`.`type` = 3
    GROUP BY `items`.`id`
```

returns a row like this:

```
item_id    category_id    review_count
1          CAT1           4
2          CAT3           2
```

The problem is that, my review count is being multiplied by the number of categories the item is in, but the query is only returning one category.

Can anyone help?

I basically want my php array to be like:

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        "item_id"=1,
        "categories"=>array("CAT1","CAT3"),
        "review_count"=>2
     )
    [1] => etc
)
```

ADDITION:
I've followed the suggestion by Mike Brant and it is an improvement, but it is not working 100% correctly. The output of the query is this:

```
item_id    category_id            review_count
1          CAT1,CAT2,CAT2,CAT1    4   <--- Incorrect number of reviews. Actual number is 2
2          CAT3,CAT3              2   <--- Correct number of reviews.
3          CAT1,CAT1,CAT1         3   <--- Correct number of reviews.
```

So basically, the returned number of reviews is correct only if the item is in 1 category.
The returned categories are almost correct, but they are being duplicated by the actual number of reviews.

If I remove the JOIN on the reviews table, I get 100% correct categories, and if I remove the JOIN on the categories, I get 100% review counts.

Can anyone explain what is going on here? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably want to utilize GROUP_CONCAT functionality in MySQL to do this

```
SELECT `items`.`id` as item_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `category`.`id`) as categories, COUNT(DISTINCT `reviews`.`review_id`) AS review_count
FROM  `items`
JOIN  `item_to_category` ON  `item_to_category`.`item_id` =  `items`.`id`
JOIN  `category` ON  `category`.`id` =  `item_to_category`.`id`
JOIN  `reviews` ON `items`.`id` = `reviews`.`item_id`
WHERE `items`.`type` = 3
GROUP BY `items`.`id`
```

This would make your result set look something like

```
item_id    category_id    review_count
1          CAT1,CAT2      4
2          CAT3,CAT4      2
```

Then when you are looping through your result set, you can convert the GROUP_CONCAT value to an array via `explode()`.

i.e.

```
$result_array = array();
while($row = [WHATEVER YOUR DB FUNCTION IS HERE]) {
    $row['categories'] = explode(',', $row['categories']);
    $result_array = $row;
}
```

**Update:**

I see the issue you are having with duplication in category id's and review counts.  I have updated query above to utilize `DISTINCT` keyword, which should solve the problem.

Comment: I would use str_getcsv instead of explode because if a category has a comma in it, you will explode the category. Using str_getcsv will keep the category with the comma together.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It almost gives the right answer, but there seems to be some multiplication/duplication going on in the data it returns. I've added the details to the bottom of my question. Thanks.